# Prevent resubmission after HTML form succeeds

Tags: html, forms

I have a contact form that I have added to my web page. After filling the form and clicking the "Submit" button, a "Successful" message appears. I did this with php request. However, when I refresh the page after this successful message, the request to send a message works again. How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use javascript `window.history.replaceState` approach to prevent a resubmit on the page refresh.

```
<script>
if ( window.history.replaceState ) {
    window.history.replaceState( null, null, window.location.href );
}
</script>
```

You can also do a page redirection to same page or different page after form submission.

```
header('Location:'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
```